# Уплотнить матрицу, удалив из неё строки и столбцы заполненные нулями

Tags: c#

Нужно уплотнить матрицу, удалив из неё строки и столбцы заполненные нулями.
Нужно именно удалить эти строки (столбцы), чтобы массив изменил свою размерность, а не просто не выводил строку (столбец).

В коде ниже, я пыталась это сделать через двумерный лист, но:

1. Это работает только для столбцов (для строк не смогла)
2. Будет иногда криво работает, если справа или слева есть 0
3. Просто на просто не хватает знаний

```
    int numСounter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if (Arr1[j][i] == 0)
                        {
                            numСounter++;
                        }
                        if (numСounter == 6)
                        {
                            for (int q = 0; q < m; q++)
                            {
                                Arr1[q].Remove(0); 
                            }
                            m--;
                        }
                    }
                    numСounter = 0;
```

Comment: Привидите код, где видно ваши попытки.

Comment: Не вижу в задаче ничего сложного. Просто идете сначала по строкам слева-направо и если вся строка состоит из 0, то удаляете. Когда обработали все строки, то идете по столбцам сверзу вниз. Вот тут чуть сложнее, но тем не менее тоже решаемо самостоятельно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, извольте-с, а почему Вы считаете, что пройтись по столбцам сложнее, чем по строкам?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Я почему-то представил входные данные не как двумерный массив, а как лист листов => строки удаляются просто, а столбцы нужно еще у всех предыдущих листах удалять. Если, как двумерный массив решать, то сложность одинаковая.

Comment: @iluxa1810, в таком случае Вы правы: немного сложнее. Не обратил внимания, что у ТС "массив" зубчатый, а не двумерный, коий всегда представляю при слове "матрица" =)

Answer (score 1):

```
static void PrintArray(int[,] rectangular)
{
    int rows = rectangular.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    int cols = rectangular.Length / rows;

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{rectangular[row, col]}\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static void PrintArray(int[][] jagged)
{
    foreach (int[] row in jagged)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", row));
    }
}

static int[,] CompactArray(int [,] rectangular)
{
    // номера строк с ненулевыми ячейками
    int[] rows = Enumerable.Range(0, rectangular.GetLength(0)).Where(row => Enumerable.Range(0, rectangular.GetLength(1)).Select(col => rectangular[row, col]).Any(elem => elem != 0)).Select(row => row).ToArray();

    // номера столбцов с ненулевыми ячейками
    int[] cols = Enumerable.Range(0, rectangular.GetLength(1)).Where(col => Enumerable.Range(0, rectangular.GetLength(0)).Select(row => rectangular[row, col]).Any(elem => elem != 0)).Select(col => col).ToArray();

    int[,] compactRectangularArray = new int[rows.Length, cols.Length];

    int newRow = 0;
    foreach (int oldRow in rows)
    {
        int newCol = 0;
        foreach (int oldCol in cols)
        {
            compactRectangularArray[newRow, newCol] = rectangular[oldRow, oldCol];

            newCol++;
        }

        newRow++;
    }

    return compactRectangularArray;
}

static int[][] CompactArray(int[][] jagged)
{
    // номера столбцов с ненулевыми ячейками
    int[] cols = Enumerable.Range(0, jagged[0].Length).Where(col => Enumerable.Range(0, jagged.Length).Select(row => jagged[row][col]).Any(elem => elem != 0)).Select(col => col).ToArray();

    // убираем нулевые столбцы
    int[][] compactArray = Enumerable.Range(0, jagged.Length).Select(row => cols.Select(col => jagged[row][col]).ToArray()).ToArray();

    // убираем нулевые строки
    return compactArray.Select(row => row.ToArray()).Where(row => row.Any(elem => elem != 0)).ToArray();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] rectangularArray = { 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        { 0, 1, 2, 0, 3 }, 
        { 0, 4, 5, 0, 6 }, 
        { 0, 7, 8, 0, 9 }, 
        { 0, 10, 11, 0, 12 }, 
        { 0, 13, 14, 0, 15 }
    };

    int[][] jaggedArray = new int[6][];
    jaggedArray[0] = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    jaggedArray[1] = new int[5] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 3 };
    jaggedArray[2] = new int[5] { 0, 4, 5, 0, 6 };
    jaggedArray[3] = new int[5] { 0, 7, 8, 0, 9 };
    jaggedArray[4] = new int[5] { 0, 10, 11, 0, 12 };
    jaggedArray[5] = new int[5] { 0, 13, 14, 0, 15 };

    Console.WriteLine("RECTANGULAR ARRAY:\n");
    PrintArray(rectangularArray);
    Console.WriteLine();
    int[,] compactRectangularArray = CompactArray(rectangularArray);
    PrintArray(compactRectangularArray);

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("JAGGED ARRAY:\n");
    PrintArray(jaggedArray);
    Console.WriteLine();
    int[][] compactJaggedArray =  CompactArray(jaggedArray);
    PrintArray(compactJaggedArray);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

// 0    0   0   0   0
// 0    1   2   0   3 
// 0    4   5   0   6 
// 0    7   8   0   9 
// 0    10  11  0   12 
// 0    13  14  0   15

// 1   2   3 
// 4   5   6 
// 7   8   9 
// 10  11  12 
// 13  14  15
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Тмп_Консоль
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numСounter = -2;
            int n = 10, m = 55;
            int[][] Arr1 = new int [n][] ;
            Random ran1 = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Arr1[i] = new int[m];
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    if (j==4)
                        Arr1[i][j] = 0;
                    else
                Arr1[i][j] = ran1.Next(0, 5);
            }

            numСounter = Findstring(Arr1);
            if (numСounter > -1)
                RemoveString(ref Arr1, numСounter);

            numСounter = FindStolb(Arr1);
            if (numСounter > -1)
                RemoveStolb(ref Arr1, numСounter);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void RemoveString(ref int[][] Arr, int strNum)
        {

            int[][] Arr2 = new int[Arr.Length-1][];            
            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if (i != strNum)
                {
                    Arr2[i] = new int[Arr[i].Length];
                    for (int j=0;j< Arr[i].Length;j++)
                        Arr2[i][j] = Arr[i][j];
                }
                else
                {
                    Arr2[i] = new int[Arr[i+1].Length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < Arr[i+1].Length; j++)
                        Arr2[i][j] = Arr[i+1][j];
                }
            }            
            Arr = Arr2;
        }
        static void RemoveStolb(ref int[][] Arr, int stolbNum)
        {

            int[][] Arr2 = new int[Arr.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
            {


                    Arr2[i] = new int[Arr[i].Length-1];
                    for (int j = 0; j < Arr[i].Length-1; j++)
                        if (j != stolbNum)
                            Arr2[i][j] = Arr[i][j];                
                else
                {                  

                        Arr2[i][j] = Arr[i][j+1];
                }
            }
            Arr = Arr2;
        }
       static int  Findstring(int[][] Arr)
        {
            int strNum=-1;
            int numСounter = 0;
            int n = Arr.Length,m;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                m = Arr[i].Length;
                for (int j = 0; j <m ; j++)
                {
                    if (Arr[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        numСounter++;
                    }
                }
                if (numСounter == m)
                {
                    strNum = i;
                    break;
                }
                numСounter = 0;
            }

            return strNum;
        }

        static int FindStolb(int[][] Arr)
        {
            int stolbNum = -1;
            int numСounter = 0;
            int n = Arr.Length, m=Arr[0].Length;


            for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
                {
                    if (Arr[j][i] == 0)
                    {
                        numСounter++;
                    }
                 }
                if (numСounter == n)
                {
                    stolbNum = i;
                    break;
                }
                numСounter = 0;
            }
            return stolbNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Убрать тестовое заполнение, добавить while !(found)
Интересно от Arr1 память очищать не нужно?